# How to import/export/derive field declarations in classes?

Tags: typescript, oop

So I want to split large base class into several modular classes in separate files. I'm using custom code to aggregate each of them into single and export the resulted class. But there is a problem: when I declare a lot of fields on the base class, I cannot import them into each of extended classes:

`base.ts`

```js
import Auth from './auth'
import Foo from './foo'
import Bar from './bar'
// other classes imports

export default class BaseClass {
  username: string
  password: string
  email: string
  telephone: string
  gender: number
  accountID: number

  constructor(init) {
    this.username = init.username
    this.password = init.password
    // ...
  }
}

export default class Result extends aggregation(
  BaseClass,
  Auth,
  Foo,
  Bar
) { }
```

`foo.ts`

```js
export default class Foo {
  login() {
    fetch(/* ... */ this.login, this.password) // <-- Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Foo'
    // How to import declaration (login, password, telephone etc) from base.ts?? 
  }
}
```

I tried "implements" keyword but it seems that it just checks if field/function is inside class, not what I want exactly. Is there a way not writing all these field declarations everytime? Perhaps, I should split classes somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to combine behaviour in one class. If yes, then you can [use mixin pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern).

For example you have two classes:

```
// @strict: false
// Each mixin is a traditional ES class
class Jumpable {
  jump() { return "I am jumping" }
}

class Runnable {
  run() { return "I am running" }
}
```

and this is the base class:

```
// Including the base
class Human {
  firstName = 'Jon';
  lastName = 'Teasl';
}
```

// Then  you create an interface which merges
// the expected mixins with the same name as your base
Then it is necessary to create an interface which will merge expected mixins:

```
interface Human extends Jumpable, Runnable {}
```

Then we can apply the mixins into the base class via JS at the runtime

```
applyMixins(Human, [Jumpable, Runnable]);

let human = new Human();
human.jump();
console.log(human.firstName, human.lastName);
console.log(human.jump());
console.log(human.run());

// This can live anywhere in your codebase:
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
          Object.create(null)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

[As an alternative, you can use an mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#how-does-a-mixin-work)

Comment: Not quite what I asked. My question is how to export *fields* declarations on top of the class, like firstName and lastName to all of mixins. The problem is that I need to use the same fields in all mixins and I'm trying to find a way to not write same fields in each class. I'm still getting linter errors "Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Foo'. ts(2339)"

Comment: Ok as a workaround for my problem, VS code has an action "Implement interface ''" which automatically adds all properties